# Naive Bayes linearity

Tags: classification, linear, naive-bayes

By theory I know that Naive Bayes Classifier is a linear one, but when I implemented the decision boundary it was a curve (not linear as shown below). Is there any explanation why this is happening? or Are there any reasons to make Naive Bayes nonlinear?

Here is the code

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

classifier = GaussianNB()

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

[image]

Comment: What implementation of NB did you use?

Comment: I have edited the question with the code I used